# how to use prepare() in php with insert query

Tags: php

```
function registerUsers($username,$password)
{
  $query=$this->link->prepare("insert into login (usnm,pswd) values (?,?)");
  $values = array($username,$password);
  $query->execute($values);
 $counts = $query->rowCount();
}
```

How to use prepare() function here.Please help me.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "pdo";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "123123";

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO login (usnm,pswd) VALUES (:usnm, :pswd)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "usnm" => $username,
    "pswd" => $password
));
```

Or you can use ? instead of array keys:

```
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO login (usnm,pswd) VALUES (?, ?)");

$statement->execute(array($username, $password));
```

Other than that, make sure that you have the db-connection initialized and accessible in the specific scope. Make sure you display errors, and see what errors (if any) are generated by your code.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

this error arrive when i execute my code